# lock text box so that a user can only input text, but not move / resize the box in indesign ?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Ive got an .indd indesign file that ive created as a template for other users to copy and fill out with images and text.

The issue is that they keep moving and / or resizing the text boxes, not by much but enough to nudge things out of alignment, am i able to lock a text box so that it cant be moved and / or resized, but only typed into ?

We are running indesign CC - latest.

Comment: No answer marked in the above linked question, but the advice from @pao is correct, at least for text boxes.

Comment: Agreed, Pao's answer is correct in that link. A User could always just unlock the text boxes again, but if the Users in question are just fellow designers using templates to create layouts, they could/should follow instructions not to do so. Accidental moving/resizing would be avoided.

Comment: As @scott mentioned in comments, that (the "Prevent Selection of Locked Objects" option) is an app preference not a document one so it won't travel with the document.